# Bartender Webservice gives a BTXML Script & ACCESS_VIOLATION Error

Tags: printing, label, barcode, bartender

We have setup a new Bartender instance in a new server due to the following BTXML error Web service integration and recently it was upgraded to BT 2019 R2 and it was working fine couple of days and now it showed the BTXML error.
But after the new installation now ACCESS_VIOLATION error is coming as shown below.

Any advises on how to fix it?

Following is the BTXML Script,

```
<XMLScript Version="2.0" Trusted="true">
  <Command Name="Print Document">
    <Print SaveAfterPrintCondition="IfModified" ReturnPrintData="false" ReturnSummary="false" ReturnLabelData="false" ReturnChecksum="false" ReturnDataSources="false">
      <Format CloseAtEndOfJob="false" SaveAtEndOfJob="false" RegenerateThumbnail="false">C:\BT\CartonLabelMixed_small.btw</Format>
      <PrintSetup>
        <Printer>Generic_ZPL</Printer>
      </PrintSetup>
      <QueryPrompt Name="ID">
        <Value>1000000008</Value>
      </QueryPrompt>
    </Print>
  </Command>
</XMLScript>
```

[image]

Following is the ACCESS_VIOLATION ERROR,

```
Print job 'CartonLabelMixed_small.btw' did not complete due to the following error: BarTender Image Dump: Exception ACCESS_VIOLATION occurred at address 0x00000001400B6FFB inside module C:\Program Files\Seagull\BarTender 2019\BarTend.exe loaded with base address 0x0000000140000000. (x64 PID:6424)
Invalid read operation at address 0x0x0000000000000080
0: 00000001407C393D MethodBase:0000000000000000 !
1: 00000001407C3E88 MethodBase:0000000000000000 !
2: 00000001407C4393 MethodBase:0000000000000000 !
3: 000000005EDCF769 MethodBase:000000005EDCF5F4 MSVCR100.dll!_CxxFrameHandler3
4: 000000005EDD0BCC MethodBase:000000005EDD0850 MSVCR100.dll!_CxxExceptionFilter
5: 000000005EDD1235 MethodBase:000000005EDD0850 MSVCR100.dll!_CxxExceptionFilter
6: 000000005EDD144D MethodBase:000000005EDD0850 MSVCR100.dll!_CxxExceptionFilter
7: 000000005EDCF66B MethodBase:000000005EDCF5F4 MSVCR100.dll!_CxxFrameHandler3
8: 00007FFE4F2D992D MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D9810 ntdll.dll!_chkstk
9: 00007FFE4F2786D3 MethodBase:00007FFE4F278250 ntdll.dll!RtlImageNtHeaderEx
10: 00007FFE4F2D8A4A MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
11: 00000001400B6FFB MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
12: 00000001400B6DCC MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
13: 00000001400D4E26 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
14: 00000001401E4066 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
15: 00000001401CBE33 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
16: 00000001400CF0E1 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
17: 00000001400FAE16 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
18: 00000001400CB67D MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
19: 00000001404202A4 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
20: 0000000140462B99 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
21: 0000000140452ADE MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
22: 00000001404510B6 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
23: 0000000140452D2F MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
24: 0000000140450CD4 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
25: 0000000140453B7E MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
26: 0000000140415276 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
27: 0000000140415040 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
28: 0000000140414E12 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
29: 0000000140415352 MethodBase:00007FFE4F2D8A10 ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher
30: 00007FFE4E687DE3 MethodBase:00007FFE4E687670 RPCRT4.dll!NdrInterfacePointerMemorySize
31: 00007FFE4E6543EF MethodBase:00007FFE4E654060 RPCRT4.dll!NdrStubCall2
32: 00007FFE4E8E222F MethodBase:00007FFE4E8E21B0 combase.dll!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke
33: 00007FFE4C7E5535 MethodBase:00007FFE4C7E47B0 OLEAUT32.dll!VARIANT_UserMarshal
34: 00007FFE4E92DE3C MethodBase:00007FFE4E927400 combase.dll!Ordinal122
35: 00007FFE4E92E482 MethodBase:00007FFE4E927400 combase.dll!Ordinal122
36: 00007FFE4E945E58 MethodBase:00007FFE4E9431E0 combase.dll!CoGetCallContext
37: 00007FFE4E94450F MethodBase:00007FFE4E9431E0 combase.dll!CoGetCallContext
38: 00007FFE4E942584 MethodBase:00007FFE4E93A2E0 combase.dll!CoMarshalInterface
39: 00007FFE4E949206 MethodBase:00007FFE4E9431E0 combase.dll!CoGetCallContext
40: 00007FFE4E9498CA MethodBase:00007FFE4E9496C0 combase.dll!CoTaskMemFree
41: 00007FFE4CD91C24 MethodBase:00007FFE4CD91730 USER32.dll!CallWindowProcW
42: 00007FFE4CD9156C MethodBase:00007FFE4CD913B0 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW
43: 000000005E734F5A MethodBase:00007FFE4CD913B0 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW
44: 000000005E735823 MethodBase:00007FFE4CD913B0 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW
45: 000000005E7674B0 MethodBase:00007FFE4CD913B0 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW
46: 000000014083C676 MethodBase:00007FFE4CD913B0 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW
47: 00007FFE0961BED1 MethodBase:00007FFE4CD913B0 USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW
48: 00007FFE39F56A53 MethodBase:00007FFE39F55E70 clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal
49: 00007FFE39F56913 MethodBase:00007FFE39F55E70 clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal
50: 00007FFE39F57165 MethodBase:00007FFE39F55E70 clr.dll!DllCanUnloadNowInternal
51: 00007FFE3A03D5CD MethodBase:00007FFE3A03C1C0 clr.dll!GetCLRFunction
52: 00007FFE3A03D426 MethodBase:00007FFE3A03C1C0 clr.dll!GetCLRFunction
53: 00007FFE3A03D2D6 MethodBase:00007FFE3A03C1C0 clr.dll!GetCLRFunction
54: 00007FFE3A03D784 MethodBase:00007FFE3A03C1C0 clr.dll!GetCLRFunction
55: 00007FFE3A03D702 MethodBase:00007FFE3A03C1C0 clr.dll!GetCLRFunction
56: 00007FFE3A03E154 MethodBase:00007FFE3A03E140 clr.dll!CorExeMain
57: 00007FFE3BD381AD MethodBase:00007FFE3BD38140 mscoreei.dll!CorExeMain
58: 00007FFE3C0C10AB MethodBase:00007FFE3C0C10A0 MSCOREE.DLL!CorExeMain
59: 00007FFE4EDA8364 MethodBase:00007FFE4EDA8350 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk
60: 00007FFE4F295E91 MethodBase:00007FFE4F295E70 ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: Can you tell me how much labels you print on a daily basis?

Comment: @Wouter this called label does not have more than 5 labels. we are still at testing stage.

Comment: @Wouter we installed a fresh BT instance in a new server now the BTXML errors doesn't come but instead gets an ACCESS_VIOLATION error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify user credentials in the integration builder? In my experience BT is not good with using the " inherit from service" option ( under integration ==> User Account) Make sure that the account you use is one that has rights on the domain and include the domain with the user. 
About the print engine, I know it sometimes has troubles when printing in large batches. Since this is not the case I also believe this is an issue with rights. There are other possibilities but I would start with the account.

Also make sure to stop the integration on the old server which had the print engine problem. Having two different integrations tugging on the same data to print can also cause some issues.

Comment: We have another integration which is running fine with 'inherit from service' option. However we found that the issue have occurred because of a printer issue. We changed the printers with correct drivers & ports now it's working. Thank you very much for your support.